# Double contents xml convert to struct structure in swift

Tags: swift

```
<Group>
<GroupName> abc <GroupName/>
<GroupAge> 15 <GroupAge/>
<test>
<desc> abc <desc/>
<title> fff <title/>
</test>
<test>
<desc> dfsdf <desc/>
<title> dsfdf <title/>
</test>
</Group>
```

I am trying to set up a struct which is suitable for parsing this xml. the number of test is variable. it may contains 3 or 4 or more tests.

```
struct GroupStruct{
}
```

How can i set up the struct. please help.
the struct should likely to be this.

```
struct GroupStruct{
var GroupName = "abc"
var GroupAge = 15
test a detail
{
}
test b detail
{ 
}
}
```

Comment: What you provide is just a template of how you want us to fill in the blank for you. It doesn't show any effort on your end to resolve the problem

Comment: i just can't think of any good solution about it

Comment: At the very least, I would expect you define how you want `GroupStruct` to be. You can start with `NSXMLParser`. Additionally, if you are on OS X, you can also use `NSXMLDocument`

Comment: i think you get me wrong. i know how to parse the xml. but i don't know how to set up this struct which is suitable for the xml

Comment: My apology for this misunderstanding. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can set up your structs, you can use strong-typing:

```
struct GroupStruct {
    var groupName: String
    var groupAge: Int
    var tests: [TestStruct]
}

struct TestStruct {
    var desc: String
    var title: String
}
```

Or tuple:

```
struct GroupStruct {
    var groupName: String
    var groupAge: Int
    var tests: [(title: String, desc: String)]
}
```

Or leave out the struct altogether and implement this with nested dictionaries.